# KOTLIN I can't delete data from sqlite database kotlin RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

I've a recyclerview and I want to delete a recyclerview item.

```
fun deleteItem(position: Int){

    ModelList.removeAt(position)
    notifyItemRemoved(position)
    notifyDataSetChanged()

}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: myRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(ModelList[position])

    holder.itemView.listRowDelete.setOnClickListener {
        deleteItem(position)
    }
```

I deleted items with this method but because of these items are in sqlite database they all come back when I restard the app. I can't reach positions from my mainactivity and I cant reach database inside of adapter. How can I delete specific item from sqlite database which I want to. Please help thank you

Answer (score 0):

For *onClickListener* , Don't rely on position from the *onBindViewHolder*

Instead get the position from holder like this

```
holder.itemView.listRowDelete.setOnClickListener {
     deleteItem(holder.adapterPosition)
}
```

InClickListeners and things that happen afterwards , get the accurate position with adapterPosition , hover over the adapter position to see the quick documentation !

If you want to call database method , I would suggest you to not call it in Adapter & rather have methods to set custom listeners to adapters which can be called with the victim (item supposed to be deleted)

have a function like this in your adapter

```
Define the listener property like this
private val myListener:MyCustomListenerInterface = MyCustomListenerInterface{}



Have a setter function to set listener
fun setListener(l:MyCustomListenerInterface){
   myListener = l
}


interface MyCustomListenerInterface{
   fun onDelete(model)
}
```

Then in your onClickListener call the onDelete of the custom listener interface like this

```
    holder.itemView.listRowDelete.setOnClickListener {
       myListener.onDelete(modelItem)
    }
```

Now When Initializing the adapter for recycler view in fragment/activity , set the listener !!